# Dragging a PDF file to a folder causes a hard freeze. How to debug? Causes?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, freeze, debug, drag-and-drop

When I drag some PDF file to some folder it causes my computer to have a hard freeze,
this even disallows me to use CrashOnCtrlScroll to generate a BSOD to see where it hung...

As my HDD & MEM are still fine, and it isn't random I think this would be a software based problem.
Maybe an Adobe PDF related DLL, an explorer extension or a driver...

- **Does anyone have an idea how I can debug this hard freeze?**

  It would be a lot easier if the stack at that moment could be read... :-(
- **What other things could be the cause of this?**

Comment: Happened after booting, tried it again when I did a reboot. Did still hard freeze. Will try again after using the computer for some time to see what would happen in that case...

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: Windows 7 Professional x64.

Comment: Specific file or any file? Specific folder or any folder? Is there anything special about the folder?

Comment: Dragging two specific PDF files to a specific folder, will test more things at a later time to be more sure... It didn't happen with files I dragged earlier this week. There is nothing special about the folder. (Side note: Please note that such questions should be placed as a comment on the question as they don't answer the question. But don't worry, a lot of users has been at that point...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how it would be able to do it... But a Shell Extension was the cause of it.

Disabled all third-party shell extensions, copy hook handlers and more solved this problem!